# Add Promise return type to method in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, return, observable

I have the following method which returns an array of TreeNodes

```
  basketItemNodes: TreeNode[] = [];

  getBasketItems() {
    this.basketService.getAllBasketItems()
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.basketItemNodes = <TreeNode []> res;            
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
      return this.basketItemNodes;
  }
```

How can I change the *return type* to a **Promise** or **Observable**?

Comment: If you need this fuction returns a observable you need to return it without subscribe. `getBasketItems() {
    return this.basketService.getAllBasketItems(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return `Observable`, then do not subscribe to it here. Instead you could simply map the response to `<TreeNode []>` and return.

```
basketItemNodes: TreeNode[] = [];

getBasketItems() {
    return this.basketService.getAllBasketItems()
      .pipe(map(res => this.basketItemNodes = <TreeNode[]> res));
}
```